# How to refactor the following?

Tags: javascript

The following code works:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < data[i].params.length; j++) {
                if (data[i].params[j].id === parameterId) {
                    data[i].params.splice(j, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

but I think this code is kind of confusing and hard to follow. How could I simplify/refactor this?

Comment: Refactoring is a very common request, and therefore unsuitable as a question title for Code Review. Instead, please tell us what this code accomplishes, ideally with examples. See [ask].

Comment: Tell us what "this" does. Also please [edit] your title to tell us about the purpose of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind that there was no disclosure about what the code achieves (at least initially), the code could be re-factored using functional methods - like [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a), etc. With those methods, you don't have to worry about incrementing a counter variable, indexing into an array/object, etc. For more information about functional programming with Javascript, I recommend [these exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/).

```
data.forEach(function(dataItem, i) {
    dataItem.params.forEach(function(param, j) {

    //param is equivalent to data[i].params[j]
    if(param.id == parameterId) {
      data[i].params.splice(j, 1);
    }
  })
});
```

See it demonstrated in the snippet below. As was mentioned in comments, there was no sample input supplied so I devised a sample.

```js
var parameterId = 3;
data = [{
    params: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'cat'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'monkey'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    params: [{
        id: 13,
        name: 'dog'
      },
      {
        id: 27,
        name: 'lemur'
      }
    ]
  }
]
data.forEach(function(dataItem, i) {
  dataItem.params.forEach(function(param, j) {
    if (param.id == parameterId) {
      data[i].params.splice(j, 1);
    }
  })
});
console.log(data);
```